# Visualisation of merge sort java?

Tags: java, sorting, merge, visualization

Hello folks I would like to do the visualisation of merge sort algorithm in java. I've already written the program in java. Where should I exactly begin for the visualisation? Are there any predefined libraries for visualisation in java?

Comment: You can use the Swing GUI library, it is pretty straightforward.

Comment: What did Google suggest?